# Dropdown value not changing

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to bind my printers name in the dropdown and managed show all the printer name in my dropdown. When I try to get the value of selected item, it show the first value for all the printer. Below is the code

### Code to bind the printer name:

```
PrintModuleAX printModuleAX = new PrintModuleAX();
var result = printModuleAX.GetAllPrinterNames();
JObject o = JObject.Parse(result);
JArray sizes = (JArray)o["PrinterNames"];
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("PrinterValue");
dt.Columns.Add("PrinterName");
for (int i = 0; i < sizes.Count; i++)
{
    dt.Rows.Add((string)sizes[i], (string)sizes[i]);
}
ddlPrinterName.DataSource = dt;
ddlPrinterName.DataTextField = dt.Columns["PrinterName"].ToString();
ddlPrinterName.DataValueField = dt.Columns["PrinterValue"].ToString();
ddlPrinterName.DataBind();
```

### code to get the selected value:

```
var printername = ddlPrinterName.Text.ToString();
var printername1 = ddlPrinterName.SelectedValue.ToString();
var printername2 = ddlPrinterName.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

`printername`, `printername1`, `printername2` show the same value even though I chose a different printer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the databinding is not happening every page load. (use if (!page.ispostback))

Answer (score 1):

Try with below code

```
ddlPrinterName.DataSource = dt;
//just specify the column name
ddlPrinterName.DataTextField = "PrinterName"; 
ddlPrinterName.DataValueField = "PrinterValue";
ddlPrinterName.DataBind();



var printername1 = ddlPrinterName.SelectedItem.Text; //gives text
var printername2 = ddlPrinterName.SelectedItem.Value; //gives value
```